# Palindrome Explanation

Tags: palindrome

I encountered the following in a [leetcode article](https://leetcode.com/articles/palindrome-number/) to determine whether an integer is a palindrome

> Now let's think about how to revert the last half of the number. For number 1221, if we do 1221 % 10, we get the last digit 1, to get the second to the last digit, we need to remove the last digit from 1221, we could do so by dividing it by 10, 1221 / 10 = 122. Then we can get the last digit again by doing a modulus by 10, 122 % 10 = 2, and if we multiply the last digit by 10 and add the second last digit, 1 * 10 + 2 = 12, it gives us the reverted number we want. Continuing this process would give us the reverted number with more digits.
>
> Now the question is, how do we know that we've reached the half of the number?
>
> Since we divided the number by 10, and multiplied the reversed number by 10, when the original number is less than the reversed number, it means we've processed half of the number digits.

Can someone explain the last two sentences please?! Thank you!

Here is the enclosed C# code:

```
public class Solution {
    public bool IsPalindrome(int x) {
        // Special cases:
        // As discussed above, when x < 0, x is not a palindrome.
        // Also if the last digit of the number is 0, in order to be a palindrome,
        // the first digit of the number also needs to be 0.
        // Only 0 satisfy this property.
        if(x < 0 || (x % 10 == 0 && x != 0)) {
            return false;
        }

        int revertedNumber = 0;
        while(x > revertedNumber) {
            revertedNumber = revertedNumber * 10 + x % 10;
            x /= 10;
        }

        // When the length is an odd number, we can get rid of the middle digit by revertedNumber/10
        // For example when the input is 12321, at the end of the while loop we get x = 12, revertedNumber = 123,
        // since the middle digit doesn't matter in palidrome(it will always equal to itself), we can simply get rid of it.
        return x == revertedNumber || x == revertedNumber/10;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is due to  the original given input, x will be decreasing by 1 digit while the reverted string increases by 1 digit at the same time. The process keeps on going until x is less than or equal to the reverted string. Hence due to the change length changes, when it terminates, we would approximately reach half of the string.

Let's visit a few examples with positive numbers  to understand the process. I would write (x,y) as the (original number, reverted string). The third example is purposely designed to show that it need not be exactly half though but the code would still work.

- The first example is 1221, where there are even number of digits.  It will go from (1221, 0)  to (122, 1) to (12, 12), at this stage, the two terms are equal and hence the process terminates and we can conclude that it is a palindrome.
- The next example is 1223, where there are even number of digits.  It will go from (1223, 0)  to (122, 3) to (12, 32), at this stage, the termination condition holds and hence the process terminates and we can conclude that it is not a palindrome.
- Now, the third example is 1211,then the sequence is (1211,0), (121, 1), (12,11), (1,112), after which we terminates from the string and it would conclude that it is not a palindrome

Now, let's make the number consists of odd number of digits:

- For 12321. It  will go from (12321, 0) to (1232, 1) to (123, 12) to (12, 123) and at this point, the condition breaks. We then divide the reverted string by 10 and we end up with (12,12) and we can conclude that it is a palindrome.
- For 12323. It  will go from (12323, 0) to (1232, 3) to (123, 32) to (12, 323) and at this point, the condition breaks. We then divide the reverted string by 10 and we end up with (12,32) and we can conclude that it is not a palindrome.
- For 12311. It  will go from (12311, 0) to (1231, 1) to (123, 11) to (12, 113) and at this point, the condition breaks. We then divide the reverted string by 10 and we end up with (12,11) and we can conclude that it is not a palindrome.

I hope these examples would help you to understand what the post mean.